# Non-Pejorative way to say "Rule Breaker" or "Non-Conformist"

Tags: synonyms

Looking for something which sums up the idea of a rule breaker who is admired rather than derided for their views. "Rebel" or "Iconoclast" carry possible negative connotations while "Maverick" feels a little too over the top. Doesn't have to be one word either, but the shorter the better.

Comment: Why is _maverick_ over the top? Apart from the fact that it’s been somewhat ruined by Sarah Palin, it seems a perfectly good word to me—it was the word that immediately popped into my mind.

Comment: Thanks Janus. It's those connotations that come to mind. Maverick is also very individual, and I should have noted that I'm looking for something that sums up more of a mindset of rule breaking.

Comment: A "rogue" is a rule breaker, but the term is often now applied in a positive way.

Comment: I don't see why a nonconformist would consider the term _nonconformist_ pejorative.

Answer (score 1):

You could describe the person as definitely an individual or more strongly a rugged individual.

Or a longer alternative, you could say that person, believes it is preferable to ask for forgiveness rather than permission.

Answer (score 1):

Such a person can be described as a free spirit.

The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/free-spirit) has this definition:

a person who does what they want with enjoyment and pleasure and does not feel limited by the usual rules of social behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can often modify the phrase "play by rules" as a way of describing a person as being someone who doesn't conform and tends to break rules whilst doing so.

Examples include:

> John:
>   Over there... that's James. He normally comes into school at 10:00 or
>   11:00.
>   Jill:
>   Is that allowed?
>   John:
>   Of course not - but James doesn't play by anyone's rules

To "not play by anyone's rules" is to have blatant disregard for the rules in order to carry out non-confirmist regimes, but it's a positive way of saying rule-breaker.

Comment: I'd say this is a bit pejorative - along the same lines as 'he thinks the rules don't apply to him'